# hibernate method calling in wbservices(marshall exception)

Tags: java, web-services, apache, hibernate, cxf

I am using apache cxf for may webservices.
In my service class there is hibernate method.
I call that method from my client call...but when call that method from client I get an exception...which is following

> 12-Mar-2012 15:21:42 org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain
>   doDefaultLogging INFO: Application
>   {http://service.simplyfiIT.net/}PasswordServiceImplService#{http://service.simplyfiIT.net/}getQuestion
>   has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.hibernate.SessionException:
>   Session is closed! 12-Mar-2012 15:21:42
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder marshallException WARNING:
>   Schema associated with http://service.simplyfiIT.net/ is null
>   12-Mar-2012 15:21:42
>   org.apache.cxf.services.PasswordServiceImplService.PasswordServiceImplPort.PasswordService

I dont find why this exception occur...

here is my hibernate method which i call from client class

> public String getQuestion(String questionID)throws HibernateException{
>         Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.currentSession();         if
>   (session == null || session.isOpen() == false) {
>                         session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSessionFactory().openSession();        }
>
> ```
>           Query q = session.createQuery("select challengequestion.question from QuestionAnswer as challengequestion where id =
> ```
>
> '"+questionID+"'");
>
> ```
>     session.close();
>
>     System.out.println("==================="+q.iterate().next().toString());
>   return q.iterate().next().toString();   }
> ```

if anyone familiar with this exception please help

Answer (score 0):

Schema associated with http://service.simplyfiIT.net/ is null. This is your problem.
In the mapping file for the QuestionAnswer class there is something like

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name = "QuestionAnswer" table = "<<table name>>">
(mapping stuff)
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Are you sure that table name exists in the database you are connecting to?

Comment: this might sound weird but, is the session open?

Comment: no the session is not open.if restart the server..then this session close exception also occur